# Which Node.js Router Should I Use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-management-system

I want to develop a CMS and I need a good routing system for Node.js.

I don't have any predecisions and I'm open any advice.

Comment: The decision should be based on features and performance. Have a look on [anumargak](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/anumargak)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Express

[express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) has a rock solid router build into it. It's got a lovely DSL syntax

```
router.get("/foo/:id/:item", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
});
```

### Director

[Director](https://github.com/flatiron/director) is an awesome standalone router that is part of [Flatiron](http://flatironjs.org/)

```
router.get(/hola/, helloWorld)
```

### Your own

For a lightweight codebase spinning up your own router using regular expressions is really easy

Comment: A super lean framework to use is [wireframe](https://github.com/aefty/wireframe). Its a mix of request routing and control flow.

Comment: @Raynos is there a way i can install and only require the router component of Express?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4#basic-routes-express.router()

Answer (score 10):

You may want to look at the module wiki to see a list of routers:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-web-frameworks-routers

I agree with the other answer on [express](http://expressjs.com/).

Answer (score 8):

The canonical web framework for NodeJS, [express](http://expressjs.com/), contains a very good, very flexible router.  If you don't know anything else about your routing needs, you should start there, as it is well supported and there is a great community to help.