# How to use JQuery to pass object data to node server and save to mongodb?

Tags: jquery, node.js, jquery-ui, mongodb, mongoose

I am using jQuery UI to allow the user to move a div. This would be the view side of things.
Now the user moves the div to a new postition (x,y). I use jQuery to get the (x,y) value.

How do I "pass" the new (id,x,y) value to my node server(controller) so the server can save it to mongodb(model)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way, it seems, would be to expose an API on your server to handle the new values.

**For the routing part:**
Check out this [article](http://www.andy-williams.net/blog/2012/11/02/routing-with-node-js/) for how to create your own routing system. You could also just use [Express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/) or [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) to setup routes (which comes at the advantage of being for free). More info on which router to choose here: [Which Node.js Router Should I Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202142/which-node-js-router-should-i-use)

**For saving in the db**
Assuming that you decide to go with Express, and that your API is : `/user/:userId/view/:viewId/position`, you could then do:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var View = new Schema({
  id: String,
  x:  Number,
  y: Number
});
mongoose.model("View", View);
```

And, in your router handler:

```
exports.post("/user/:userId/view/:viewId/position", function (req, res) {
    //Find user with userId in db
    //...
    //Find view with viewId in db
    var view = req.params.viewId;
    View.findOne({id:view}, function(err, result){
          if(err || !result){
            console.log("cannot find view "+view);
            res.end();
          }
          else {
            //update value of x and y
            var x = req.body.x;
            var y = req.body.y;
            //...
         }
});
```

**For sending the data**
Finally, on the client side, use jQuery to make the POST request:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: window.location.href+"/view/"+viewId+"position",
        data: {
            x: 200,
            y: 150
        },
        success: function(d) {
            //Position saved
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //Something bad happened
        }
    });
```